# how does linux know how much physical memory is available?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory

I am trying to understand which Linux kernel function reads the amount of available physical memory.
After that, where this information is stored?

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough for the kernel to know just the amount of available physical memory: it also needs to know where in the processor's address space that memory is located.

How this is achieved is specific to each hardware architecture.

- on x86 systems, the firmware figures it out using chipset-specific methods, and provides that information to the operating system kernel:

  - on systems using legacy BIOS, the information is available using the BIOS function `INT 0x15, EAX = 0xE820`: see [this osdev.org wiki article](https://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_(x86)) for details.
  - on systems using UEFI firmware in native mode, the memory map is provided by the firmware to the bootloader/OS through [UEFI System Table](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/04_EFI_System_Table.html#id6), specifically using the `GetMemoryMap` service in the [UEFI Boot Services table](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/04_EFI_System_Table.html#efi-boot-services-table)
- on many other architectures, the (initial) memory map can be provided to the kernel by the [Device Tree data](https://docs.kernel.org/devicetree/usage-model.html) appended to the kernel, if the system firmware does not provide it in any other way, or if you first need a bit of hardware-model-specific information before you can usefully get the information from the firmware.